# Link explicitly to libc (-lc)

Tags: c, unix, linker, shared-libraries, libc

Should I explicitly link my program or library against libc, when using libc symbols?

i.e., `cc ... -lc`

The question applies to the Makefile in case of a program, and both the Makefile and the pkg-config file in case of a library.

And as a side question: what if I don't use any libc symbols at all? That would probably be a very useless program, but I'm curious.

I seem to recall some article or book recommending doing so, but now I can't find it.  Is there any situation in which doing so or not doing it can be problematic?

Edit:

I'm normally using `gcc` and `clang`.  (I also edited the third paragraph to explicitly ask about Makefiles and pkg-config files.)

Comment: 1. Most compilers when calling the linker will add the right flags for linking libc automatically. 2. Depends on the compiler, but you still would need libc for the CRT stuff like the function that calls main, exits after return from main etc.

Comment: You should probably mention what specific compiler you are using

Comment: 1) I'm not familiar with any "mainstream" compilers that don't implicitly link to libc automatically.  Cross compilers for embedded systems are a different story entirely. 2) Q: What happens if you don't make any libc calls?  A: The linker simply  won't try to link in most external routines that aren't needed.  This may - or may not - affect the size of your executable.  3) Some compilers/linkers allow you to explicitly *exclude* the standard library, if you wish.  For example: /https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nodefaultlib-ignore-libraries

Comment: The `-lc` option is supplied to the linker automatically by the `cc` compiler/linker front end. If you use `cc` to do the compiling and `ld` to do the linking explicitly, you need to run `ld` with the `-lc` option to link against the libc library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I explicitly link my program or library against libc, when using libc symbols?

No. From [POSIX cc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/cc.html):

> The standard C-language library is automatically available to the C-language program.

> what if I don't use any libc symbols at all?

Then still do not link explicitly against libc and let compiler link with it automatically.

> Is there any situation in which doing so or not doing it can be problematic?

When you are writing a kernel, bare-metal software, or other low-level program specific to some environment you are working with, and you do not want to link the standard library. Also, when you do not accept the license of the library.

Comment: The last paragraph seems to be more about when one should not link against libc, more than if one should not explicitly ask to link against libc (but of course if you don't want to link you can't ask it to link), but seems fair for completeness.

Comment: What about other languages. Those may be able to interface through some language-dependent magic, and if they link against my C library, they might not get linkage against libc, right? Unless I provide `-lc` in my `pkg-config` file.  Especially, if I provided a static library?

Comment: I was thinking of c++.  Does c++ link by default to libc also?

Comment: `The last paragraph seems to be more about when one should not link against libc, more than if one should not explicitly ask to link against libc` och right, so it's a difference between linking "implicitly" and linking "explicitly and implicitly"? Then there's no difference and the answer would be just "no".

Comment: `What about other languages` What about them? `Those may be able to interface` why would they interface at all? These are other languages, they have they own standard library or don't have it, in either way C does not exist for them. `if I provided a static library?` Too broad - static library of?

Comment: `Does c++ link by default to libc also?` The C++ programming language is a language - it does not link, it's a language. It may be (it may be not) that a specific implementation of C++ STL requires to have symbols from C standard library. It's up to that implementation. In practice, to use `ostream` you have to have `fopen` and yes, C++ _compilers_ link with C++ and C standard library by default. A language is it whole - the written construct and the library, and the compiler should provide them all.

Comment: Fair enough. (Btw, in the second mention to c++ I meant c++ as in the name of the compiler.  Sorry for the confusing language :)

Comment: As I recall, the `c++` as the executable name is not standardized (in POSIX). It's just something people started doing to mimic `cc`, and in both cases it's just a link to the real executable (I mean, like, it's not _the name_ of the compiler). Either way, clang++ links with libc++ and g++ links with libstdcpp.

Answer (score 1):

> what if I don't use any libc symbols at all?

Then your program is freestanding and does not require linking with the standard library.

If you use `gcc` you need to compile it with `-nostdlib` command-line option.

Comment: Hmm.  The program `int main(void) {}` does not (explicitly) use any symbols from the C standard library, but it can still be compiled for a hosted implementation.  I'm not inclined to agree that whether a program references the standard library is the criterion for whether it is freestanding.

Comment: Since the interpretation of "use" is a bit ambiguous, I think this answer is correct in one sense, so I upvoted it, but I think some more explanation as @JohnBollinger suggested would be good.